# Create a variable in a balanced data frame that is a transpose of another column

Tags: r, transpose, dplyr

I have balanced data set and want to create a new variable based on the transpose of an existing matrix form of another variable. At the moment I am doing this using an intermediate matrix, as such...

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
d <- crossing(orig = LETTERS[1:4], dest = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(16)) 

m <- matrix(d$x, nrow = 4)

d <- d %>%
  mutate(x_trans = c(t(m)))
d
# # A tibble: 16 x 4
#    orig  dest        x x_trans
#    <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 A     A     -0.626  -0.626 
#  2 A     B      0.184   0.330 
#  3 A     C     -0.836   0.576 
#  4 A     D      1.60   -0.621 
#  5 B     A      0.330   0.184 
#  6 B     B     -0.820  -0.820 
#  7 B     C      0.487  -0.305 
#  8 B     D      0.738  -2.21  
#  9 C     A      0.576  -0.836 
# 10 C     B     -0.305   0.487 
# 11 C     C      1.51    1.51  
# 12 C     D      0.390   1.12  
# 13 D     A     -0.621   1.60  
# 14 D     B     -2.21    0.738 
# 15 D     C      1.12    0.390 
# 16 D     D     -0.0449 -0.0449
```

... but i was wondering if there is a way to create such a variable without the matrix/breaking the chian, as I have multiple periods and variables that I want to do this for. At the moment I am using a `for` loop, but perhaps there is a clever way to this with `mutate`, some other function and `group_by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant with the loop. But if you is you dont want to break then chain you can simply do like this:

**Code**

```
d <- crossing(orig = LETTERS[1:4], dest = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(16),
         x_trans = x %>% 
           matrix(nrow = 4) %>% 
           t() %>% c())
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
   orig  dest        x x_trans
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A     A     -0.626  -0.626 
 2 A     B      0.184   0.330 
 3 A     C     -0.836   0.576 
 4 A     D      1.60   -0.621 
 5 B     A      0.330   0.184
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```r
set.seed(1)
d <- crossing(orig = LETTERS[1:4], dest = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(16)) %>%
  mutate(x_trans = unlist(split(x, dest)))

# # # A tibble: 16 x 4
#   orig  dest        x x_trans
# <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A     A     -0.626  -0.626 
# 2 A     B      0.184   0.330 
# 3 A     C     -0.836   0.576 
# 4 A     D      1.60   -0.621 
# 5 B     A      0.330   0.184 
# 6 B     B     -0.820  -0.820 
# 7 B     C      0.487  -0.305 
# 8 B     D      0.738  -2.21  
# 9 C     A      0.576  -0.836 
# 10 C     B     -0.305   0.487 
# 11 C     C      1.51    1.51  
# 12 C     D      0.390   1.12  
# 13 D     A     -0.621   1.60  
# 14 D     B     -2.21    0.738 
# 15 D     C      1.12    0.390 
# 16 D     D     -0.0449 -0.0449
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern in selecting values. We can use any logic to create indices to subset data. Here, I am using `outer` to generate the indices and then using `slice` to get data in the particular order.

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% slice(c(outer(seq(1, n(), 4), 0:3, `+`)))

#   orig  dest     x
#  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 A     A     -0.626 
# 2 B     A      0.330 
# 3 C     A      0.576 
# 4 D     A     -0.621 
# 5 A     B      0.184 
# 6 B     B     -0.820 
# 7 C     B     -0.305 
# 8 D     B     -2.21  
# 9 A     C     -0.836 
#10 B     C      0.487 
#11 C     C      1.51  
#12 D     C      1.12  
#13 A     D      1.60  
#14 B     D      0.738 
#15 C     D      0.390 
#16 D     D     -0.0449
```

Answer (score 0):

`group_split` then select from `d` where `dest` equal to group's first `orig`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
d %>% 
  group_split(orig) %>% 
  #Try `map` if you need the ouptput as a list
  map_df(~.x %>% mutate(x_trans = filter(d, dest==.x$orig[1]) %>% pull(x)))

# A tibble: 16 x 4
   orig  dest        x x_trans
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A     A     -0.626  -0.626 
 2 A     B      0.184   0.330 
 3 A     C     -0.836   0.576 
 4 A     D      1.60   -0.621 
 5 B     A      0.330   0.184 
 6 B     B     -0.820  -0.820 
 7 B     C      0.487  -0.305 
 8 B     D      0.738  -2.21
 ...
```